# Automatically Refreshing Rails Metal In Development Mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, sinatra, jrubyonrails

I am trying to develop a rails metal endpoint using sinatra, but is proving to be a pain because I have to restart the server every time I change the code. I am in Jruby and running from within a larger Java app. Is there an easy way to make this code refresh for every request?

Answer (score 3):

Just because I like abstract abstraction, this is Ryan's code v2:

```
def every s
  loop do
    sleep s
    yield
  end
end

every 1 { `touch tmp/restart.txt` }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to automatically reload sinatra code, however:

If you were running passenger, you could try running in irb:

```
 loop do
   `touch tmp/restart.txt`
   sleep(1)
 end
```

Which will then tell the passenger instance to restart the application.